# What is the data-type for :symbol?

Tags: info, symbols

When looking at 'Face attributes' in emacs you have keywords like `:family`, `:height`, `:weight` etc.

When using `use-package` you have keywords like `:ensure`, `:init`, `:config` etc.

1. What are the terms for describing these symbols where you have a colon prepended to a name?
2. Where in info can I find out more? Please use the format: `(info "(manual)DOCUMENT NODE")` which can be searched for by using `M-:` e.g. `(info "(elisp)Lisp Data Types")`

Comment: The funny thing is that you've *used* the correct terminology when describing them in your question :)  I think `C-h i g (elisp)Constant Variables` is the most specific manual node (it is linked to from the one Tobias has given).

Comment: @phils After reading the documentation that Tobias mentioned and stumbling towards (elisp)Constant Variables as you have mentioned, I realised that 'keyword' was the exact descriptor. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual Section 9.2. ["Symbol Components"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html):

> Most symbols can have any Lisp object as a value, but certain special symbols have values that cannot be changed; these include nil and t, and **any symbol whose name starts with ‘:’ (those are called keywords)**. See Constant Variables.

This page can be reached with <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp)Symbol Components")` <kbd><RET></kbd>

Comment: Thank you. `M-:` `(info "(elisp)Constant Variables")` `<RET>` as phils mentioned is also a good read.